# CSide API - Warning: file_get_contents(http://cside.pt/UIAPI/token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, api

Anyone ever used CSide API? (http://www.cside.pt/UIAPI/)
I don't know what's the problem, it might be my code or the credentials.

```
<?php
$api_url = 'http://cside.pt/UIAPI/token';

$client_id = 'xxx';
$client_secret = 'xxx';

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic"."\r\n".
                     base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret")
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);

print_r($result);
?>
```

I'm getting this error

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://cside.pt/UIAPI/token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in C:\xampp\htdocs\wetrig\CI\api\test.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wetrig\CI\api\test.php on line 18

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: BTW: it is not really safe to post credentials around the web even if it is Stack Overflow

Comment: Sorry, i have deleted it